# datagridview not showing all columns when adding columns

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I have datagridview column from database FullName and then I add columns manually from code the position 1 to 5 so I added 5 columns. I can't get all the rows and columns when I tried to get in DataTable at the end.

```
DataTable table = database.Execute("Select FirstName + ' ' + LastName as FullName from People");
                dataGridView1.DataSource = table;

                for (int i = 1; i <= 5 ; i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewColumn()
                {
                    HeaderText = i.ToString(),
                    CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell(),
                    Width = 30
                }
                );
            }

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
```

Comment: your for-loop only goes through 1-5 (so 4)...try using a foreach-loop using the Datatable.

Comment: @Johan Looks like it loops 5 times to me. (Since `int i = 1; i <= 5 ; i++` it will start at 1 and hit 2, 3, 4, and 5)

Comment: My question is why I can't see all the rows in dt DataTable at the end?

Comment: Because you have added 5 columns.. while you are selecting only one column from the database as per your query. I do not understand why are you adding five columns? what you want, please explain more.

Comment: This is because I need to add week numbers from 1 to 52 and then color them which week they will be off from work.

Comment: It should be `for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++)` .. I think ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, the issue here is that you are manually adding columns to your `DataGridView`, which has a ***separate*** collection of columns than your `DataSource`. When you get the `DataTable` from your `dataGridView1.DataSource`, you are getting just the "FullName" column from the original query that you performed (because the collection of columns in that `DataTable` still only contains just the one column).

To fix this, add this line to your `for` loop:

```
(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).Columns.Add(i.ToString());
```

Another note, you can just do:

```
DataTable dt = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
```

instead of:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); // Don't need to create empty DataTable here
dt = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
```

This will keep you from unnecessarily allocating memory.

Answer (score 0):

Well...

If the Cory's solution does not work for you try to add columns within

```
BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
{ 
  // for example 
    var Code = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
                {
                    Width = 50,
                    DataPropertyName = "Code",
                    DefaultCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle()
                    {
                        Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft,
                        ForeColor = Color.Black,
                    },
                    HeaderCell = new DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell()
                    {
                        Style = new DataGridViewCellStyle()
                        {
                            Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
                        }
                    }
                };
                Code.HeaderText = "Code";
                dgvWorkTypes.Columns.Add(Code); 

}));
```